# I set up a Health function and if-statement for if Health is lower than 0 but it won't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I was programming a silly game that has no purpose for me to get some practice in coding in C#, but even this simple if-statement is stumping me. Yeah, I know, kind of stupid, but I have been looking for 15 minutes and decided to post on here. I made a Health variable and told the game to destroy gameobject when health is at or less than zero, however, even that doesn't seem to work. I am going to make the assumption I am missing some sort of semi-colon. We will see.

I have already tried bypassing the Dead(); function and just said if Health is at 0 or less, destroy gameObject and even that didn't work.

```
void Dead()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}

void Update()
{
    if (Health <= 0)
    {
        Dead();
    }
}

void ApplyDamage(int TheDamage)
{
    Health -= TheDamage;
}
```

}

Inferably I want the game to destroy the enemy when it is at 0 or less.

Comment: I don't use Unity, but have you ensured that `Destroy` has the behavior that you're expecting, and that `Update` is actually being called, and that health is 0?

Comment: Well, never used a unity. But my bet is you have to call the update. If I were you, I'll change the design and implement an event.

Comment: Is this attached to a GameObject? Do you ever call `ApplyDamage`? Could you post the complete code?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Update gets called by the engine. Here's a [primer for Unity3d's Event Lifecycle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

Comment: A little bit offtopic: You can use properties for checking conditions of new values instead of making an if-clause in your update-method. The most important questions were already asked by derHugo.